# CSS mask-image doesn't work with filter:blur() over a video.

Tags: css, html5-video

This is a very specific issue but I'm attempting to mask an image that is blurred and place it directly over a video so that there is a gradient fade into obscuring half of the video.

What happens when all 3 of these conditions are present (Video, blur, and mask-image) is that overlaying (masking) image will start blurring into transparency at the borders of the CONTAINING div, instead of it's own borders. This means that no matter how large I make the image mask or however I move it, it will never touch and completely obscure the edges of the video.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="background-image-mask></div>
    <video><source src=""></video>
</div>

#background-image-mask {
    height:105%;
    width: 105%;
    background-image: url('...');
    -webkit-image-mask: gradient(...);
    filter:blur(5px);
}

#container {
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

You can see a codepen here: https://codepen.io/mcheah/pen/mGEbPW

Does anyone know of a way to get around this? Some CSS property that I'm unaware of? Or another potential workaround? 
Thanks so much!

Comment: Your gradient syntax is **extremely** old- you might want to fix that first.

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed it and it appears to have not changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs a workaround, I simply included an additional image behind the original image, which was not blurred out.

ie:

```
<img src="123.jpg" class="blur-me">
<img src="123.jpg" class="normal">
```

This covers the edges and you can't really tell that the edges are not as blurred.